# Cannot update useState variable to dynamically update React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel, dynamic

I want to dynamically update my page's content when an excel file is uploaded. I can handle the upload and convert it into a json array. The problem is that when I use setContent(json[x].Data) the Content stays empty.

I tried setting it just to the json array, but it did not work either.

This is my code:

```
const [Content, setContent] = useState([]);

const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result;
      const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" });
      const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
      const parsedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
  
      setContent(parsedData[10].Data);
      console.log(Content);
    };
  };
```

Full source code: [here](https://github.com/AdyStudios/LogiReader)

The console.log shows, that the Content is just an empty object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setting state (as in setContent) requests a new re-render.  It doesn't immediately update the value of Content.  So that's why calling console.log(Content) right after setContent(), will still show the old value of Content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand how React lifecycle (and useState) works.
When you set new value with setContent, Content will update AFTER component re-render.
So when you are trying to log Content into console, Content has its default value - which is an empty array.

Edit:
The useState updating looks like this:
set function -> rest of code reading -> re-render (component's content has been updated -> useState variable update

Comment: Even if I log after the function ended, it's still empty. I cannot use the contents of Content in the return function after setting it.

Comment: So for example I have a section like this in the return: ```<dd>{Content.age}</dd>``` and I want to update that, but after using the setContent, it cannot find the Content.age even if it is in the parsedData[10].Data.

Comment: Can you please show me all your code?

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/AdyStudios/LogiReader

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the updated value in console, you can either do

```
console.log(parsedData[10].Data)
```

inside your function, as you have done already or do console logs outside your function as below:

```
console.log(Content).
```

Hope this helps.